# J2BUgzilla : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfig

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, bugzilla

I am using J2BUgzilla to integrate with bugzilla using eclipse .Below is my code in java class file.

```
 BugzillaConnector conn=new BugzillaConnector();

     conn.connectTo(bugzilla url");
```

But as i run my test i am obtaining error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlrpc/client/XmlRpcClientConfig
    at t.setUp(t.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

what i have done so far is like this.I want to connect to bugzilla to report a bug programmaticallyFor this i have created a java class and have added j2bugzilla2.1.jar to project path and have written the needed code.but i got error at the above code , that is where i am trying to connect to bugzilla.

Comment: missing class files / jars from classpath

Comment: Check if you have xmlrpc jars in your classpath.

Comment: Apache XML-RPC Client Library, http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/

Comment: i have added xmlrpc-2.0 in project path

Comment: was this a typo?: `conn.connectTo(bugzilla url");`  You don't have a matching `"`

Comment: @ sircapsalot, its not a typo issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its due to absence of specific library. Use org-apache-xmlrpc.jar.
You can download it from [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachexmlrpcjar.htm)